# Rebuilding executable images from memory

Tags: executable, compression, relocation

Is it doable? Are there any tools? I have an EXE compressed in a non-standard way and would like to get the decompressed version this way. Can relocation be undone or inverted, so that I can save a decompressed EXE version automatically?

PS: this is not for cracking, although it could be used to facilitate that. I just need to change some text strings in the compressed EXE.